# Get result from three tables using join from which one table contain multiple result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have three tables with the following columns and data:

table_one

```
id  | balance
100 | 10.00
101 | 5.00
102 | 8.00
```

table_two

```
id | number
100 | 0890980980
100 | 7657657655
101 | 7657657656
102 | 1231231233
```

table_three

```
id  | name      | active
100 | nameOne   | 1
101 | nameTwo   | 0
102 | namrThree | 1
```

Now my query will be

```
Query 1. SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE balance <= 8
Query 2. SELECT number(only first_matched_row) FROM table_two WHERE table_one.id = table_two.id
Query 3. SELECT name FROM table_three WHERE table_three.id = table_one.id AND table_three.active = 1
```

How can I join these three queries and get a single query. 
Please note that table_two will get multiple rows so I want take the first matched row and omit the rest where table_two.id matches.

Expected Result:

```
id  | name      | number
100 | nameOne   | 0890890890
102 | nameThree | 1231231233
```

**SOLVED ANSWER:**

```
Select onetwo.id, three.name, two.number from 
(Select two.id from
(SELECT id as id1 FROM table_one WHERE balance <= 8)one
inner join
table_two two on one.id1 = two.id
)onetwo
inner join
table_two two on two.id=onetwo.id
inner join
table_three three on three.id = onetwo.id AND three.active = 1 group by two.id
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try:

```
      Select onetwo.id, three.name, onetwo.number from 
(Select two.id from
(SELECT id as id1 FROM table_one WHERE balance <= 8)one
inner join
table_two two on one.id1 = two.id
)onetwo
inner join
table_three three on three.id = onetwo.id AND three.active = 1 group by onetwo.id
```

You can have more elegant queries using advanced RDBMS, but not with MySQL unfortunately.

Comment: Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: SELECT id FROM table_one WHERE balance <= 8 is working fine but 
Select * from
(SELECT id FROM table_one WHERE balance <= 8)one
inner join
table_two two on one.id = two.id
limit 1 returns only one. The actual result should return the id number 101 and 102. Also if balance is <= 10 then id number 100 (all 3 rows) are returning when limit 1 is omitted.

Comment: if balance <= 10 the query still returns multiple id (number 100). The second query is perfect. returning just 3 rows but when executing the complete query it returns 4 rows (id 100 is duplicated)

Comment: I removed 'group by two.id' from second query and added at the end of the query and it worked it seems. Can you verify?

Comment: Yes this will work, I didn't understand your requierement as you describe it. 
Please update the answer with your new query.